# Which algorithm is best for Text Summarization?

Tags: data-mining, text-mining

Cosine, Dice, Jaccard out of these algorithms which algorithm is best for Text Summarization?

Answer (score 2):

None of them *is* an algorithm for text summarization at all.

They are similarity measures that can be applied for *two* texts.

Answer (score 2):

**Extractive summarization**

Extractive summarization means identifying important sections of the text and generating them verbatim producing a subset of the sentences from the original text; while abstractive summarization reproduces important material in a new way after interpretation and examination of the text using advanced natural language techniques to generate a new shorter text that conveys the most critical information from the original one.

*This is where the model identifies the important sentences and phrases from the original text and only outputs those.*

**Abstractive Summarization**

Abstractive Summarization is more advanced and closer to human-like interpretation. Though it has more potential (and is generally more interesting for researchers and developers), so far the more traditional methods have proved to yield better results.

*The model produces a completely different text that is shorter than the original, it generates new sentences in a new form, just like humans do. In this tutorial, we will use transformers for this approach.*

```
reference_text = """Artificial intelligence (AI, also machine intelligence, MI) is intelligence demonstrated by machines, in contrast to the natural intelligence (NI) displayed by humans and other animals. In computer science AI research is defined as the study of "intelligent agents": any device that perceives its environment and takes actions that maximize its chance of successfully achieving its goals. Colloquially, the term "artificial intelligence" is applied when a machine mimics "cognitive" functions that humans associate with other human minds, such as "learning" and "problem solving". See glossary of artificial intelligence. The scope of AI is disputed: as machines become increasingly capable, tasks considered as requiring "intelligence" are often removed from the definition, a phenomenon known as the AI effect, leading to the quip "AI is whatever hasn't been done yet." For instance, optical character recognition is frequently excluded from "artificial intelligence", having become a routine technology. Capabilities generally classified as AI as of 2017 include successfully understanding human speech, competing at a high level in strategic game systems (such as chess and Go), autonomous cars, intelligent routing in content delivery networks, military simulations, and interpreting complex data, including images and videos. Artificial intelligence was founded as an academic discipline in 1956, and in the years since has experienced several waves of optimism, followed by disappointment and the loss of funding (known as an "AI winter"), followed by new approaches, success and renewed funding. For most of its history, AI research has been divided into subfields that often fail to communicate with each other. These sub-fields are based on technical considerations, such as particular goals (e.g. "robotics" or "machine learning"), the use of particular tools ("logic" or "neural networks"), or deep philosophical differences. Subfields have also been based on social factors (particular institutions or the work of particular researchers). The traditional problems (or goals) of AI research include reasoning, knowledge, planning, learning, natural language processing, perception and the ability to move and manipulate objects. General intelligence is among the field's long-term goals. Approaches include statistical methods, computational intelligence, and traditional symbolic AI. Many tools are used in AI, including versions of search and mathematical optimization, neural networks and methods based on statistics, probability and economics. The AI field draws upon computer science, mathematics, psychology, linguistics, philosophy and many others. The field was founded on the claim that human intelligence "can be so precisely described that a machine can be made to simulate it". This raises philosophical arguments about the nature of the mind and the ethics of creating artificial beings endowed with human-like intelligence, issues which have been explored by myth, fiction and philosophy since antiquity. Some people also consider AI to be a danger to humanity if it progresses unabatedly. Others believe that AI, unlike previous technological revolutions, will create a risk of mass unemployment. In the twenty-first century, AI techniques have experienced a resurgence following concurrent advances in computer power, large amounts of data, and theoretical understanding; and AI techniques have become an essential part of the technology industry, helping to solve many challenging problems in computer science."""
```

**Abstractive Summarize**

```
len(reference_text.split())
from transformers import pipeline
summarization = pipeline("summarization")
abstractve_summarization = summarization(reference_text)[0]["summary_text"]
```

**Output**

```
In computer science AI research is defined as the study of "intelligent agents" Colloquially, the term "artificial intelligence" is applied when a machine mimics "cognitive" functions that humans associate with other human minds, such as "learning" and "problem solving" Capabilities generally classified as AI as of 2017 include successfully understanding human speech, competing at a high level in strategic game systems (such as chess and Go)
```

**Extractive summarization**

```
from sumy.parsers.plaintext import PlaintextParser
from sumy.nlp.tokenizers import Tokenizer
from sumy.summarizers.lex_rank import LexRankSummarizer
parser = PlaintextParser.from_string(reference_text, Tokenizer("english"))
summarizer = LexRankSummarizer()
extractve_summarization  = summarizer(parser.document,2)
extractve_summarization = ' '.join([str(s) for s in list(extractve_summarization)])
```

**Extractive Output**

```
Colloquially, the term "artificial intelligence" is often used to describe machines that mimic "cognitive" functions that humans associate with the human mind, such as "learning" and "problem solving".As machines become increasingly capable, tasks considered to require "intelligence" are often removed from the definition of AI, a phenomenon known as the AI effect. Sub-fields have also been based on social factors (particular institutions or the work of particular researchers).The traditional problems (or goals) of AI research include reasoning, knowledge representation, planning, learning, natural language processing, perception and the ability to move and manipulate objects.
```

Answer (score 0):

seq2seq deep learning models are mostly used for this case,
this is a [blog series](https://github.com/theamrzaki/text_summurization_abstractive_methods#blogs) that talks in much detail from the very beginning of how seq2seq works till reaching the newest research approaches

Also this [repo](https://github.com/theamrzaki/text_summurization_abstractive_methods) collects multiple implementations on building a text summarization model, it runs these models on google colab, and hosts the data on google drive, so no matter how powerful your computer is, you can use google colab which is a free system to train your deep models on

If you like to see the text summarization in action, you can use this [free api](https://eazymind.herokuapp.com/arabic_sum).

I truly hope this helps